# Access array variables outside for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops, datatables

i am trying to populate  a table using datatables jquery library , the problem encountered is that only the last value  is displayed ,the values are accessed by looping through data stored in json . Here is my code :-

```
for (var i = 0; i < json_parsed.Users.length; i++) {
    var user = json_parsed.Users[i];
    if (user.position == "GK") {
        goalkepeers = [{
            "playerID": user.playerID,
            "playerName": user.playerName,
        }];
    }
}



$('#myTable').dataTable({
    "aaData": goalkepeers,
    "aoColumns": [{
            "mDataProp": "playerID"
        }, {
            "mDataProp": "playerName"
        },

    ]
});
```

Everything works fine but only one data is displayed in my table , the array should be like this

```
goalkepeers = [{
    "playerID": player1ID,
    "playerName": player1Name,
}, 
{   
    "playerID": player2ID,
    "playerName": player2Name,
}];
```

Any help will be appreciated , Thanks again :-)

Comment: You should push into `goalkeepers` array, not reassign a new array at each step of the loop.

Comment: You keep reassigning `goalkepeers`(sic) to a new array on each iteration through the loop. Presumably you meant to create an array and `push` a new object into the array?

Comment: What he said, but in code: `goalkepeers .push(your json)`

Comment: Try `goalkepeers.push({"playerID": user.playerID,"playerName":user.playerName})` you are overwriting the array with each iteration.

Comment: ridiculous how many answers can't even use proper indentation.

Comment: Looks like you're using an old version of `dataTables`. Try and use the new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, Declare goalkeepers globally and then declare goalkeeper everytime in the loop and push it into goalkeepers array:

```
var goalkeepers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < json_parsed.Users.length; i++){  
             var user = json_parsed.Users[i];
             if(user.position=="GK"){
                var goalkeeper= {
                "playerID": user.playerID,
                 "playerName":user.playerName,
                     };
                goalkeepers.push(goalkeeper);
               }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot rohit, but i get an error in "aaData": goalkepeers, , it says Uncaught ReferenceError: goalkeepers is not defined. but i can see it being defined at line 1.

Comment: Sorry , my bad , it worked :-) Thanks a lot , appreciate :-)

Comment: Glad to help! otherwise i was also about to post any other approach to achieve the same :) .

Answer (score 1):

it happens because you're replacing the values:

```
var goalkepeers= [];
for (var i = 0; i < json_parsed.Users.length; i++){  
    var user = json_parsed.Users[i];
    if(user.position=="GK"){
        var obj={
            "playerID": user.playerID,
            "playerName":user.playerName,
            };
        goalkeepers.push(obj);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Amin, but i get an error in "aaData": goalkepeers, , it says Uncaught ReferenceError: goalkeepers is not defined. but i can see it being defined at line 1.

Comment: Sorry , my bad , it worked :-) Thanks a lot , appreciate :-)

Answer (score 0):

define the array before the loop

```
goldkeepers= array();
```

then inside the loop just do

```
goalkepeers.push({
        "playerID": user.playerID,
        "playerName": user.playerName,
    });
```

in your code your array is overwritten by the next json_parsed.Users element every time so the final result is an array with just the last element